# Maximizing OpenTK Window doesnt resize the shown objects

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have the problem, that whenever I maximize the window, the size of the objects doesn't change like it should. If I just resize the window, the objects scale as they should, only maximizing doesn't work.

But the changes happen after the window *leaves* maximized mode. So after going back to normal window size, I can only see a small part of the rendered object.

[The example](https://github.com/opentk/LearnOpenTK/tree/master/Chapter1/2-HelloTriangle) is really simple; it just draws some triangle.

I don't think there's anything interesting happening; but they included this override:

```
protected override void OnResize(ResizeEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, Size.X, Size.Y);
            base.OnResize(e);
        }
```

So I guess this resizes the objects when resizing the window. I tried something similar for the maximizing event, but it didn't work:

```
protected override void OnMaximized(MaximizedEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, Size.X, Size.Y);
            base.OnMaximized(e);
        }
```

I even put `GL.Viewport(0, 0, Size.X, Size.Y);` at the beginning of the `OnRenderFrame(...)`-Function, but that didn't help either. (Size.X and Size.Y are correct all the time, i checked them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first call `base.OnResize` and then update the viewport size, you don't need to override `OnMaximized`:

```
protected override void OnResize(ResizeEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e); // this should be called immediately
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, Size.X, Size.Y);
}
```

Looking at the OpenTK source code you can see that `Size` is updated in `base.OnResize(e)` method so you are using stale values.